# Copy file from guest OS having only terminal to Host OS having Desktop environment

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro as my host OS with KDE as a desktop environment. And arch Linux terminal without desktop environment in Oracle virtualbox as guest. I only have a terminal in the Arch Linux.

Without installing a desktop environment in Arch Linux VirtualBox is there any way to copy the file present in my arch Linux to Manjaro host OS or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [install and setup ssh server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Shell) in your guest OS and then use scp to transfer files among both the OS.